# How does one go about incorporating location based services into a social network?

Tags: php, geolocation, social-networking

I am currently working on a special interest social network.  The part that I'm having trouble with is the location of individual users.

My ideal solution would be a system where users enter their city/state and/or zip code, and could search for other users within their own area.

What I think separates my question from many existing threads is my needs and my resources.  I don't have much capital at all to invest in a paid database, nor do i need all the features offered by the ones i've come across.  I'm really looking for suggestions in which direction I need to go in.  I've seen a lot of threads with similar ideas, but none that give the type of answers i need for my project.  I'm not sure where to start with this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Also, I'm building my application in php5.

Comment: what type of capital do you think it requires? these barebones (<$10/month) hosting packages include MySQL: http://order.1and1.com/Hosting?__lf=Static&linkOrigin=&linkId=hd.nav.hosting.linux so you could store the locations, and use the Haversine formula to find nearby users: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html#findnearsql oh, and you could consider using `navigator.geolocation` to ease the data grab

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I'm familiar with the Haversine formula and I can afford the domain and hosting plan.  What I mean by the paid database is an external database that I could match city/state combinations to latitude/longitude coordinates.  I'm sorry, i failed to mention that i have the flu right now, and I'm trying very hard to be coherent, but probably failing :(.  How standard is the navigator.geolocation object? I've actually never used it before.  And wouldn't i need a fallback for that?  Such as : If the javascript fails, i would still need a way to grab the users lat/lon right?

Comment: Thats the type of direction that I'm looking for, if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

these barebones hosting packages include MySQL... [1and1.com](http://order.1and1.com/Hosting?__lf=Static&linkOrigin=&linkId=hd.nav.hosting.linux)

so you could store the locations, and use the Haversine formula to find nearby users: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html#findnearsql

For getting the data in Lat/Lng format, you could consider using `navigator.geolocation`...it's fairly well supported, but you could do a test for it: `if(navigator.geolocation)` and if it's NOT, provide a text field for city/state or ZIP, and then geocode that to get to Lat/Lng (google has a service here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/ ) but it does have some limitations, like 2500 queries/day unless you pay for an upgraded license

Actually, even if the navigator approach is available, you might want to provide a confirmation step (in case their ISP is returning an different location)...like "you appear to be HERE, is this accurate, or would you like to supply your own location"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Robot Woods, Your answer inspired some creative googling that lead me to the answer to my problem.  Yahoo offers PlaceFinder!  http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/

PlaceFinder can be used to get a Latitude/Longitude from a user inputted city/state combination or a zip code. And best of all... Its Free!!!  Fits my budget perfectly!